com.android.tools.build.debugsymbols is NOT generated in iguana
My AS has been upgraded to Iguana recently and now I have these:
Android Gradle Plugin Version: 7.4.0
Gradle Version: 7.5
After building the aab file, it shows that the "com.android.tools.build.debugsymbols" is not generated in BUNDLE-METADATA any more. This causes the warning message in Play Console when releasing the app:
This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug.
This is what I have in build.gradle(app):
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx.xxxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        ndkVersion "24.0.8215888"
        ndk {
            debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
        }
    }

As some post suggestions, I tried to comment out
ndkVersion "24.0.8215888"

but not working at all. Also tried to download the latest ndk version from SDK manager and applied it to ndkVersion above, still not working. From what I read in the document, I don't need to specify ndkVersion at all so that the default tested ndk version will be used, though I don't find which is the default ndk version for my ide at all.
This issue happens since upgrading to Iguana, and it appears it's related to the Gradle related changes. Wondering if this could be a bug from AS or Gradle? How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.
